# Git says nothing to commit after running ng build --prod

Tags: angular, git, visual-studio-code

I saved the changes to my files in the VSCode terminal. Ran the following commands:

```
git status(This showed the changes.)
git add .
git status (This showed the files added)
git commit -m "My commit message."
git push (This showed the files were pushed up to git).
```

Then I run the `ng build --prod`. The build runs without a problem. I run `git status` and I get the following:

$git status
On branch qa
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/qa'.

nothing to commit, working tree clean

I'm on the correct branch. I've rebuilt this a number of times without a problem. Anyone have any idea how to fix it.

Comment: (* shows the **commits** were pushed to git)

Comment: What's wrong here? If you pushed why wouldn't the branch be up-to-date with the origin branch? What are you expecting instead?

Comment: After seeing the answers you must know that it is not good practice to keep compiled/build output code in git.

Answer (score 2):

Angular builds are usually saved in dist folder which is in root path.

In .gitignore file, paths are declared which omits in source control. dist folder is one among them. That is the reason you are unable to see the files during `git status`.

Here is the sample of .gitignore file contents.

```
# See http://help.github.com/ignore-files/ for more about ignoring files.

# compiled output
/dist -----> /dist is mentioned in this file
/tmp
/out-tsc

# dependencies
/node_modules

# IDEs and editors
/.idea
.project
.classpath
.c9/
*.launch
.settings/
*.sublime-workspace
```

Comment: @mwave317 Please note that dist folders are generally not committed because they can change regularly and frequently. Plus it should be able to be generated from the rest of the files anyway

Answer (score 0):

your / dist directory is in the .gitignore file at the root of the project, if you need to upload the compiled version to git (it can be done, but it is not a good practice), you should remove this directory from the .gitignore file, and run `git status` again to check

Comment: I was able to resolve the issue by doing a ng build --prod --watch